# Change .ejs to .html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, heroku, ejs

How can I make the following server.js code work for .html files instead on .ejs in Node JS. Thanks!

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// set the port of our application
// process.env.PORT lets the port be set by Heroku
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// make express look in the public directory for assets (css/js/img)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// set the home page route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

// ejs render automatically looks in the views folder
res.render('index');
});

app.listen(port, function() {
console.log('Our app is running on http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just remove these lines:

```
// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// set the home page route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // ejs render automatically looks in the views folder
  res.render('index');
});
```

and add your .html files to public/.

Testing this with this code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// set the port of our application
// process.env.PORT lets the port be set by Heroku
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// make express look in the public directory for assets (css/js/img)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Our app is running on http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

and this directory structure

```
├── package.json
├── public
│   └── index.html
└── server.js
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: @lessio It says cannot GET/ on heroku now

Comment: I would suggest this is some configuration problem with heroku. The code seems to work perfectly fine to me! Adding more info to my answer